# Wordpress on new Firebase hosting

Tags: wordpress, ssl, firebase, hosting

I've found out about new Google Firebase Hosting recently and I was wondering if that would work for Wordpress website? 
I got a bit confused them talking about static websites & web apps even though as far as I know Wordpress is dynamic...right? on their website it says:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/#key_functions

> Whether you are deploying a simple app landing page or a complex Progressive Web App, Hosting gives you the infrastructure, features, and tooling tailored to deploying and managing static websites.

It looks like a nice Hosting platform for web, especially that they provide SSL certificates, but is it good for Wordpress?

Thanks!

Comment: There isn't much point in using firebase hosting if you aren't using firebase

Comment: I do not know of hosting solutions, but there are firebase plugins for wordpress. https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/firebase

Answer (score 3):

I THINK it would be possible, you still need your SQL+PHP server and you should use it as WordPress backend, you need the WordPress REST API  and a plugin with hooks in transition_post_status, comments... and whatever you want to show in your front end, use WordPress API endpoints to send the JSON to the firebase database... after your template should use a Javascript framework in order to make JSON requests to the firebase database and show the data in the browser... It would be difficult but I think it could be the cheaper and best solution ever for a high traffic website (plus all the benefits of firebase).

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Firebase doesn't provide any of the requirements necessary for Wordpress, that being MySQL and PHP on the server side. Firebase provides a JSON store accessible via an API, and static hosting for apps that can access said API.